# Cannot mkdir: Too many links

Tags: debian, inode

I'm trying to untar several tar files. I encountered something like this

> tar: NCBI_SRA_Metadata_Full_20110601/SRA037312: Cannot mkdir: Too many links

Is there a limit to the number of files that can exist in a directory? I checked du -i the IFree is still 51M. So it doesn't looks to me like inode is running out.

Comment: You've asked the wrong question.  You're making a subdirectory, as the error message tells you.  You should therefore be asking about limits on _subdirectories_ within a directory, not on files.  (There _are_ limits on files.  But the `EMLINK` error here results from a _different_ limit on subdirectories.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit to the number of files that can exist in a directory.  That limit depends on what file system you're using though, and potentially on what options were used when you formatted the file system.

By default on ext3 (and I believe ext2 as well), the limit is 32,000 files.

EDIT: Further reading, as well as my own testing, suggest that the 32,000 file limit is no longer an issue in modern kernels with ext3.  *However*, there is still a 32,000 sub-directory limit, so while JdeBP's comments are technically correct, that huggie asked, and I answered the wrong question... the gist of the answer is the same.

Consider this test:

```
$ mkdir asdf
$ for x in $(seq 1 32000); do mkdir $x; done
mkdir: cannot create directory `31999': Too many links
mkdir: cannot create directory `32000': Too many links
```

Comment: See [this discussion from December 2001](http://lists.svlug.org/pipermail/svlug/2001-December/012367.html) for ext2.  Note, by the way, that you've answered the wrong question.  The limit you're talking about is a limit on _subdirectories_ within a directory (resulting from the limit on the link count of the parent directory which is increased for each subdirectory) not on _files_ within a directory.